# How to delete the rest of the records after a pattern which occurred for the second time in a .CSV file

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk

I have a .CSV file which has few records after a header, however, there is a duplicate header just before the end of the file and after that duplicate header are few more records(which I do not need). Is there a way that I could check for the pattern of the header which occurred for the second time and delete the rest of the file after that duplicate header? Below is the example of the file.

> col0,col1, col2, col3     , col4        , col5,       col6      ,
>   1value0,1value1,1value2,1value3,1value4,1value5,1value6,
>   2value0, 2value1, 2value2, 2value3, 2value4, 2value5, 2value6,
>   3value, 3value1, 3value2, 3value3, 3value4, 3value5, 3value6,
>   2value0, 4value1, 4value2, 4value3, 4value4, 4value5, 4value6,
>   5value0, 5value1, 5value2, 5value3, 5value4, 5value5, 5value6,
>   6value0, 6value1, 6value2, 6value3, 6value4, 6value5, 6value6,
>   ,,,,,,,
>   ,,,,,,,
>   ,,,,,,,
>   (n-1)value0, (n-1)value1, (n-1)value2, (n-1)value3, (n-1)value4, (n-1)value5, (n-1)value6,
>   (n)value0, (n)value1, (n)value2, (n)value3, (n)value4, (n)value5, (n)value6,
>   col0,col1, col2, col3     , col4        , col5,       col6      ,
>   1,unwanted, records, after, the, duplicate, header
>   2,unwanted, records, after, the, duplicate, header
>   3,unwanted, records, after, the, duplicate, header

Here the output that I am expecting is shown below

> col0,col1, col2, col3     , col4        , col5,       col6      ,
>   1value0,1value1,1value2,1value3,1value4,1value5,1value6,
>   2value0, 2value1, 2value2, 2value3, 2value4, 2value5, 2value6,
>   3value, 3value1, 3value2, 3value3, 3value4, 3value5, 3value6,
>   2value0, 4value1, 4value2, 4value3, 4value4, 4value5, 4value6,
>   5value0, 5value1, 5value2, 5value3, 5value4, 5value5, 5value6,
>   6value0, 6value1, 6value2, 6value3, 6value4, 6value5, 6value6,
>   ,,,,,,,
>   ,,,,,,,
>   ,,,,,,,
>   (n-1)value0, (n-1)value1, (n-1)value2, (n-1)value3, (n-1)value4, (n-1)value5, (n-1)value6,
>   (n)value0, (n)value1, (n)value2, (n)value3, (n)value4, (n)value5, (n)value6,

P.S: I have GNU sed version 4.1.5 and GNU Awk 3.1.5

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is the second header intended to be different from the initial one (missing 'col0'), so that it is only a partial match, or is this just a typo?

Comment: Am sorry, they both are the same... I just checked and corrected it.. Thankssss

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk 'a~$0{exit}NR==1{a=$0}1' file
```

Comment: Could you please explain the code, what it is doing? Will be very helpful... Just trying to learn something new every day... Thanks in advance...

Comment: `NR==1` runs the action for first line, which is store the line in variable `a`. `1` is for enabling the print. the first pattern `a~$0` checks if variable `a` is initialized and has a value like your first line. If it does, then just exit coz you don't need to print the header line and what follows it again.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed 4.2.1):

```
sed 's/,/\n/8;T;s/\n.*//;q' file
```

This works by trying to replace the 8th `,` by itself and if it fails to bail out and print the line as usual. Most lines (in your example) have only 7 comma's, so will be left alone, whereas the line containing the duplicate header will then be shortened and the printed out when the processing is quit.

Answer (score 2):

Probably way more complicated than it needs to be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{flag=0} $0==head{flag=1}; NR==1{head=$0}; flag==0{print $0}' file
```

Comment: This worked, but could you please explain the code, so that, it would be helpful in using it next time... appreciate for your time...

Comment: The BEGIN block is run before the file is read and initialize a flag variable. `$0==head` checks if the current row is equal to the variable "head", and if so sets flag=1. NR==1{head=$0} sets head to the first row in the file (the header). flag==0{print $0} prints all rows where flag==0 (ie all rows before the repeated header). The code is longer than it needs to be, but easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk 'd<2{print} /col1, col2, col3 , col4 , col5, col6/{d++}' file
```

Comment: This answer was written before you corrected the question hence do not use this answer. It does basically the same thing as fileunderwater's solution: Matches exactly "col1, col2, col3 , col4 , col5, col6" though (increasing match counter d++) and only prints lines before the 2:nd occurance (d<2).